# Jackson's JsonNode with JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jackson

I'm writing a JAX-RS web service that returns JSON back to the client, and I'm trying to use the `org.codehaus.jackson` libraries for dealing with JSON objects.  The problem I'm having is that my [`JsonNode`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) isn't getting properly serialized before it is returned to the client.  There are a bunch of extraneous properties in the response.  I would like the simplest JSON representation of the `JsonNode` to be returned.

Here's a (contrived) example:

```
@GET
@Path("user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonNode getUser() {
    ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    node.put("user", "jDoe");
    return node;
}
```

The JSON response from this is pretty ugly:

```
{"object":true,"elements":[{"textual":true,"textValue":"jDoe","binaryValue":"jDoe","valueAsText":"jDoe","valueNode":true,"containerNode":false,"missingNode":false,"array":false,"object":false,"pojo":false,"number":false,"integralNumber":false,"floatingPointNumber":false,"int":false,"long":false,"double":false,"bigDecimal":false,"bigInteger":false,"boolean":false,"null":false,"binary":false,"booleanValue":false,"intValue":0,"longValue":0,"doubleValue":0.0,"decimalValue":0,"bigIntegerValue":0,"valueAsInt":0,"valueAsLong":0,"valueAsDouble":0.0,"valueAsBoolean":false,"elements":[],"fieldNames":[],"fields":[]}],"fieldNames":["user"],"fields":[{"key":"user","value":{"textual":true,"textValue":"jDoe","binaryValue":"jDoe","valueAsText":"jDoe","valueNode":true,"containerNode":false,"missingNode":false,"array":false,"object":false,"pojo":false,"number":false,"integralNumber":false,"floatingPointNumber":false,"int":false,"long":false,"double":false,"bigDecimal":false,"bigInteger":false,"boolean":false,"null":false,"binary":false,"booleanValue":false,"intValue":0,"longValue":0,"doubleValue":0.0,"decimalValue":0,"bigIntegerValue":0,"valueAsInt":0,"valueAsLong":0,"valueAsDouble":0.0,"valueAsBoolean":false,"elements":[],"fieldNames":[],"fields":[]}}],"containerNode":true,"valueNode":false,"missingNode":false,"array":false,"pojo":false,"number":false,"integralNumber":false,"floatingPointNumber":false,"int":false,"long":false,"double":false,"bigDecimal":false,"bigInteger":false,"textual":false,"boolean":false,"null":false,"binary":false,"booleanValue":false,"intValue":0,"longValue":0,"doubleValue":0.0,"decimalValue":0,"bigIntegerValue":0,"valueAsInt":0,"valueAsLong":0,"valueAsDouble":0.0,"valueAsBoolean":false}
```

I would prefer it to be simply

```
{"user":"jDoe"}
```

Am I missing something?  I don't understand why there would be problems serializing a simple JsonNode into JSON.

For what it's worth, returning a [`JSONObject`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.web2mobile.json.help/javadoc/com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.html) from the JSON4J libraries works as expected, but I would prefer using Jackson's libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as-is, so I am suspecting that maybe there is a version incompatibility.
Since Jersey uses Jackson 1.x (1.8 or 1.9), you need to be using same version; 2.0 classes are in different Java packages, to allow 1.x and 2.x to co-exist (to avoid forcing upgrade).

So make sure you are using same version as Jersey does.

Comment: I found this answer because I have the same problem, however - I use Jackson version 2.4.5 consistently + jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17 (which is different project, all other jersey libs are 2.17). Still it returns "ugly" JSON instead of the real content. Funny enough - if I take that `List<JsonNode> result` and return it this way instead `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(result).build()` (that is `Result` is returned type), everything is OK. On other places where I use custom JSON objects, returning entity directly works just fine.

Comment: @virgo47 I think there have been subtle bugs in this area, actually, having to do with whether exact type is forced by JAX-RS provider or not. So make sure to use the latest patch (2.4.6 or 2.5.3) whenever possible. I agree in that it should just work, but the integration with JAX-RS has been tricky to get exactly right, esp. due to Java Type Erasure.

Comment: Eh, don't know how I found 2.4.5 as the newest version - good news is that after switching to 2.5.3 (+explicitly adding to POM some jackson core dependencies that came in transitively in older versions ;-)) everything works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @virgo47 2.4.5 is quite new so it was very close. There is 2.4.6 however. But yes, glad that 2.5.3 helped!