# JacksonUtils readTree not parsing properly

Tags: java, json, jackson

In a JAX_RS server endpoint, a service is supposed properly parse this:

```
{"user_id":"ngerrie"}
```

into a JsonNode that can be properly rendered on return.

```
String sampleRole="{\"user_id\":\"vespasian\"}"
List result = new List<Object>
result.add(new ObjectMapper().readTree(sampleRole));
```

The return takes the object and serializes it with

```
return Response.ok(result,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

Instead of getting `{"user_id": "ngerrie"}`, it returns this:

```
            {
                "array": false,
                "bigDecimal": false,
                "bigInteger": false,
                "binary": false,
                "boolean": false,
                "containerNode": true,
                "double": false,
                "float": false,
                "floatingPointNumber": false,
                "int": false,
                "integralNumber": false,
                "long": false,
                "missingNode": false,
                "null": false,
                "number": false,
                "object": true,
                "pojo": false,
                "short": false,
                "textual": false,
                "valueNode": false,
                "nodeType": "OBJECT"
            }
```

The class is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper 
g:com.fasterxml.jackson.core a:data-bind v:2.8.7

These change started happening after an upgrade.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with Jackson since the example works just fine with a Spring web application.

Comment: @Rad Were you using the example I mentioned, or some example from the Jackson or other package?

Comment: Exactly the above code with the same version. BTW the expected result is an array not an object.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a sample project to reproduce the problem and add the link to the post.

Comment: This probably doesn’t have anything to do with the _parsing_, the problem is in the serialization of the result (regardless if if was parsed or constructed manually from scratch). And it might be caused by library version mismatch. See the same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593933/jacksons-jsonnode-with-jax-rs

Comment: Hi Woodsman. Please don't sign your posts here - the user card is thought to be enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I never knew what caused this specific error, but I ended up reverting my branch, creating a brand new Eclipse workspace and Tomcat server instance.  As near as I can tell, the version I was using was the same used when the code worked.  But alas, somehow, it just became easier to burn it down and recreate it.  If I had to guess, @Mormegil was probably not incorrect.